# Cakephp migrations - General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am having issues creating a foreign key in some migrations.

I have the following:

**20180926184217_Courses.php**

```
public function change()
{
    $table = $this->table('courses', ['id' => true, 'primary_key' => ['id']]);
    $table
        ->addColumn('name', 'string', ['default' => null, 'limit' => 150, 'null' => false])
        ->addColumn('town', 'string', ['default' => null, 'limit' => 50, 'null' => true])
        ->create();
}
```

**20180926191546_Scorecards.php**

```
public function change()
{
    $table = $this->table('scorecards', ['id' => true, 'primary_key' => ['id']]);
    $table
        ->addColumn('course_id', 'integer', ['default' => null, 'limit' => 10, 'null' => false])
        ->addColumn('description', 'string', ['default' => null, 'limit' => 255, 'null' => true])
        ->addColumn('tee', 'string', ['default' => null, 'limit' => 15, 'null' => false])
        ->addForeignKey('course_id', 'courses', 'id', ['delete' => 'SET_NULL', 'update' => 'NO_ACTION', 'constraint' => 'fk_scorecard_course'])
        ->create();
}
```

When I run `bin/cake migrations migrate` I get the following error:

Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint in [***/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/PdoAdapter.php, line 167]
2018-09-26 19:12:50 Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint in ***/vendor/robmorgan/phinx/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/PdoAdapter.php on line 167

Can anyone help please? I have looked at other answers on here and none seemed to help.

Dave

Comment: What version of phinx are you using? You can find this in your composer.lock file

Comment: You can just use `$table = $this->table('courses');` as primary key column named `id` is created by default. Have you checked if `courses` table is being created at all? Maybe by query log on the DB?

Comment: @DerekFulginiti I am using phinx 0.10.6.  Whats odd is when i use these migrations in an existing project using a postgres DB they work fine. But in my new project using a mysql DB I get the error.

Comment: As mentioned already, the next step would be to make sure that the courses table is in fact created.

Comment: Yep the courses table is being created. Also the scorecards table is being created just without the foreign key.

Comment: Set `course_id` column limit to exact as `courses` table's `id` column.

Answer (score 1):

You can't SET_NULL on delete action when your column is not nullable. Change the code and you will be ready for your migration.

Comment: that was the solution for me! Thanks