# Laravel 8 : Unable to create foreign key - "General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two migrations.

`2021_07_21_115002_create_resources_table.php`

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('resources', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title', 200);
        $table->smallInteger('issue_year');
        $table->unsignedInteger('publisher_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('resources', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('publisher_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('publishers');
    });
}
```

and

`2021_07_21_115313_create_publishers_table.php`

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('publishers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 200);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

It keeps on failing.

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `resources` add constraint `resources_publisher_id_foreign` foreign key (`publisher_id`) references `publishers` (`id`))

  at D:\wp-local\ignou\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:692
    688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
    693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    694▕             );
    695▕         }
    696▕     }

  1   D:\wp-local\ignou\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:485
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint")

  2   D:\wp-local\ignou\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:485
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

I have found over 8 to 10 answers for this particular problem and none seems to be working.

- [General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint [ Laravel 5.8 ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609984/general-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-laravel-5-8)
- [SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854693/sqlstatehy000-general-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-laravel)
- [Laravel General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60456975/laravel-general-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)
- [Cakephp migrations - General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52524774/cakephp-migrations-general-error-1215-cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add a foreign key in the first migration(`2021_07_21_115002_create_resources_table` ):

```
$table->foreign('publisher_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('publishers');
```

that references the table `publishers` that does not yet exist because it will be setup in the following migration(`2021_07_21_115313_create_publishers_table.php`).

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Move the foreign key statement to the latest migration:

```
// 2021_07_21_115313_create_publishers_table.php

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('publishers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 200);
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('resources', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('publisher_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('publishers');
    });
}
```

2. Move the `Schema::create('publishers')` to the first migration:

```
// 2021_07_21_115002_create_resources_table.php

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('resources', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title', 200);
        $table->smallInteger('issue_year');
        $table->unsignedInteger('publisher_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('publishers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name', 200);
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('resources', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('publisher_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('publishers');
    });
}
```

Keep in mind which migrations are already applied because these cannot be modified without performing a database reset.

Comment: This worked! Its interesting, how does laravel decide which migration to run first ??

Comment: It uses the date in the filename of the migration, in your case `2021_07_21_115002` comes before `2021_07_21_115313`.

Comment: Could you mark the answer as solution(by using the checkmark under the voting arrows if this solution has worked?

Comment: Ah! got it. Thanks! I will mark your answer after 5 mins are completed. It won't let me yet.

Answer (score 0):

first of all ,
change code from

```
$table->unsignedInteger('publisher_id')->nullable();
```

to

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('publisher_id');
```

, because of latest laravel 8 documenation :[enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

,